# Trying to update Mysql by toggling switch using AJAX PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax PHP to update MySQL database every time I press on and off button without reloading the page.

However, it does not update the data in my database.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id = "checkStatus" name="checkStatus" class="switcher-input" checked="">
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; // has $conn variable.

if(isset($_POST['checkStatus'])){
    if($_POST['checkStatus']=='ON'){
    $status = 1; //to save in DB as boolean
    }else if($_POST['checkStatus']=='OFF'){
    $status = 0;
    }
  $sql = "UPDATE `recipe` SET `status`=$status WHERE creator='$uid'";
    //nev
  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
?>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#checkStatus').on('click', function() {
        var checkStatus = this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
         alert(checkStatus);
        $.post("loginsystem/includes/recipe.inc.php", {"checkStatus": checkStatus},
        function(data) {
            $('#checkStatus').html(data);
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: how you obtain $uid on server  ?? and which data type is the column creator?

Comment: Are any console errors showing? Does your request response show any PHP errors? Is error reporting enabled? Does your server logs show anything?

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use parametrised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: $uid is obtained from dbh.inc.php document.

Comment: check if the 'mysqli_query($conn,$sql);' line is reached, and try to do '$sql' on mysql console (or workbench)

Comment: answer all the questions, not just the first one. `SHOW CREATE TABLE recipe` will sow the table structure and list the data types.

Comment: scaisEdge // Creator is a foreign key from user table. It's varchar(50). equals to $uid and it works on other files such as join, login, find the password and etc.
Script47 // I had something to do after posting a comment. My excuse. I never got an education on Computer Science, so I should learn to display errors perhaps. 

Dragonthoughts/ This is just for my little project so I guess I don't have to worry too much about security.

Comment: Thanks for the comment dan, I tried to update table from terminal and the query works fine there . (substituted $ fields of course). Well, I'm pretty sure that table structure won't help solving my problem. I'm trying to see whether my php reaches 'mysqli_query' line.

Comment: DongHyun Song // $uid was the problem. Not properly parsed from included php file. Thank you! 감사합니다.

Comment: It was $uid problem. Thank you all and apologize you all for not stating my problem clearly. I have been learning php html for just two months and I am not fully aware how to use console. It was especially confusing since I have never used AJAX before so I thought it was Javascript problem. Thank you again for trying to help me.